# Create Bin file with imgBurn and command line

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, imgburn

How can i create a bin file from audio cd with ImgBurn using command line? My operating system is windows 7 64 bit.

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines of the following should work.

> Start "Construieste_ISO" /wait /min "C:\Program
>   Files\ImgBurn\ImgBurn.exe" /MODE BUILD /BUILDMODE IMAGEFILE /SRC
>   "c:\ARHIVA\" /DEST "c:\Iso\arhiva.iso" /FILESYSTEM "ISO9660 + Joliet"
>   /VOLUMELABEL "Arhiva"  /OVERWRITE YES /rootfolder yes /start /LOG
>   "c:\Iso\iso.log" /close /noimagedetails

[Source](http://forum.imgburn.com/index.php?showtopic=18593)